# High pitched noise in my condenser mic

Tags: microphone, noise, usb, high-frequency, problem

I am having a high pitched voice in my microphone wherever I speak and am quite troubled by it. I read some similar questions to this problem but still haven't find a solution for it.

When I plugged in the mic, the noise is coming straight in the mic.

I tried switching usb port, and I think it's not a ground loop since I plugged in when using it with my laptop. And I used it with a usb port too.

I have attached a short recording of me with the mic:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KTSY4-Vo52ZNDu6foDbmPZKbmKCITu_m/view?usp=sharing

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no details were provided by the OP making this unanswerable

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, some other people don't have that problem.  So the question is what difference there may be to other people.  They may use a different microphone.  They may use a different USB sound interface.  They may use a different power supply.  They may use different recording software on a different laptop or with different settings, like sample rates, file formats, recording options.  They may use different sample rates.  They may position the microphone differently and they may have different possibly problematic devices in the room, like energy saving lamps with sub-par power supply.

You don't bother giving any details about your setup relevant to your problem.  That makes it impossible to give any useful advice about what may be going wrong.

It doesn't help that a paragraph like

> I tried switching usb port, and I think it's not a ground loop since I plugged in when using it with my laptop. And I used it with a usb port too.

does not even begin making sense, never mind the detail level.  You need to be a whole lot more specific or this question will be closed as unanswerable.